# Use Button Click To Send Image To New Page. WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

How do you use a button to send an image within the same page to another page in the application via the button click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method that is called on the button click, I'd use the application properties to store your image. Something like this (you will want to put a data type on your image):

```
Application.Current.Properties.Add("myImage", System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage myBmp);
Window newWindow = new Window();
newWindow.Show();
```

Then on the window that opens, grab the image from the app properties like this (note that you'll want to cast your image as they image type you want):

```
transferredImage = (MYIMAGETYPE)Application.Current.Properties["myImage"];
var brush = new ImageBrush();
            if (image != null)
            {
                brush.ImageSource = image;
                btnCustomerPhoto.Background = brush;
            }

Application.Current.Properties.Clear();
```

Of course, you don't have to clear the current properties if you don't want to, but I do to ensure I don't have anything sticking around I don't want.

There are other ways to do this but the application properties are easy to use and then get rid of.

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try this. If I wanted to pass selected data from one list view to another listview on the same page would I use a similar technique?

Comment: Indeed you can. To add, for instance, a string value:

    Application.Current.Properties.Add("textBoxValue", textBoxControl.Text);

Then to retrieve that string value:

    string s= (string)Application.Current.Properties["textBoxValue"];